# Layout as keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

Is it a good idea to use an XML file for soft keyboard, and assigning 26 + 10 keys for a-z,0-9?
I want to ask how much memory is it going to take.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it eats up too much memory. After all it is a very limited number of objects.

It's not nested loops creating thousands of objects and you don't put hundreds of images into a list.